# Use external gem for Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

I'm currently developing three Rails applications that are going to use the same database and and the same models. In order to keep them in sync, I want to move these models into an independent gem.

I've read the [RubyGems](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) guide for creating my own gem but I'm not sure of how some things should be handled (e.g. database credentials (`database.yml`), tests for the models, migrations...)

Any thoughts on best practices or pointers to existing gems providing this behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I posted my answer before you re-stated your question. Can you clarify what you mean when you say "use the same database"? Do you mean *literally* the same database (e.g., a single Postgresql instance). Or, do you mean same database *structure*? They are very different things.

Comment: Literally the same database, a single Postgresql instance :)

Comment: Oooooooh! Then why not just put all your migrations in one of your apps and then configure the other two apps to connect to that database instance? Seems much easier than ginning up a gem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migrations go in your gem.

You can cause them to be included in your containing app by putting this in your gem's `engine.rb` file (when using Rails::Engine):

```
'lib/your_gem/engine.rb'

module YourGem
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer :append_migrations do |app|
      unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
        config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
          app.config.paths["db/migrate"] << expanded_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You don't *have* to use `Rails::Engine` (in fact, it comes with some unneeded overhead). But, if you're doing this for the first time, it may be the easiest thing to do.

`schema.rb` will be auto-generated in your containing app's `db` directory as is normally the case when you run `rake db:migrate`.